# nginx instruction to redirect all pages with html or php or no extension to php-engine without leaving any extension on the url

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I tried many solution to achieve this and always "something" is not working:

The file on the server are stored as: filename.php

I need all the pages in the site - whether address as siteurl/filename.html or siteurl/filename or siteurl/filename.php 
to be forward to the php engine and to be displayed as siteurl/filename

what combination of instruction should I use to achieve this ?

```
location / {

            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
    }
```

then:

location ~ .php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;

```
            include             /etc/nginx/includes/php_fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass        mysite_php_backend;

            fastcgi_buffers     38 4k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    }
```

tried several other combination but everytime - something fails. 
right now no redirection at all but it serves both php and non php names.

Comment: If you want the URL to change in the browser, you need to redirect. Which means another request. Are you OK with that?

Comment: yes, as long as all URLs will end up the same way

Comment: Try adding `rewrite (.*)\.(html|php)/?$ $1 redirect;` before the `try_files`

Comment: This almost solves it, but if I request the .php file - it will not rewrite. it says with php extensions. works great for .html  though.